# Use SYSREC as table for next Unload

Tags: sql, db2, jcl

I've searched BMC foruns and DB2 foruns but I found no solution. I wanted to know if it is possible to use the output of BMC Unload Plus, SYSREC, as a table to unload from in the next JCL step?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by using a table unload to then be a table to unload a table. My guess is that you are unloading/extracting a list of tables, and then want that to drive subsequent unloads of those tables.

The answer would entirely depend upon the capabilities of BMC Unload. There is a very comprehensive manual, which explains thing such as doing multiple table unloads. This can be found here [BMC Products for DB2](https://webapps.bmc.com/DocCenter/index.jsp?nav=/0).

With regard to SYSREC this link takes you directly to [SYSREC and SYSRED data sets in UNLOAD PLUS](https://webapps.bmc.com/DocCenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.bmc.doccenter.adu.refManual/GUID-C186FAAF-EDF0-4960-82D3-775247E86B22.html).